# Comparar título de imagen en un ImageButton y una cadena de texto

Tags: java, android, clase, class, id

Estoy haciendo en Android Studio un juego muy sencillo en el cual tengo un array con X banderas. He creado un método que me muestra dos banderas al azar y debajo la pregunta de la bandera de un país. Cuando el programa me busca dos banderas al azar, luego me busca entre esas dos seleccionadas una al azar para mostrar la pregunta de debajo. Entonces, lo que quiero ahora es que al pulsar el ImageButton correcto me diga que he acertado y sino que he fallado.

Con el siguiente método puedo sacar con el método substring la cadena del país que es pero ahora lo que quiero es que lo compare con la foto que lleva el ImageButton. De la misma manera que hago un setImageResource para poner la imagen al botón, ahora quiero extraerlo para con un substring hacer que solo me quede el nombre del país y así compararlo con la cadena que me muestra el país de la pregunta.

```
public int GenerarPregunta(){
    String respuesta;
    int num1 = generarAleatorioBanderas();
    int num2 = generarAleatorioBanderas();

    int[] numerosGenerados = {
            num1,
            num2,
    };

    botonUno.setImageResource(arrayBanderas[num1]);
    botonDos.setImageResource(arrayBanderas[num2]);

    paisTexto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paisTexto);
    int numPais = generarAleatorioPais();
    int paisFinal = numerosGenerados[numPais];
    Log.d("paisFinal", String.valueOf(paisFinal));
    String cadenaPais = getString(arrayBanderas[numerosGenerados[numPais]]);
    cadenaPais = cadenaPais.substring(13);
    cadenaPais = cadenaPais.substring(0, cadenaPais.lastIndexOf("."));
    paisTexto.setText(cadenaPais);
    //paisTexto.setText(arrayBanderas[numerosGenerados[generarAleatorioPais()]]);
    
    respuesta = cadenaPais;
    return respuesta;
}
```

y en el método onclick es donde al pulsar sobre la foto quiero extraer que foto tiene y si coincide con la respuesta que devuelvo en el anterior método.

Busco algo como getImageResource aunque se que no existe. He estado mirando con tag pero no se si en este caso se podrá hacer.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Pozo, un posible enfoque, es crear una clase **Imagen**, y luego le pides al objeto aquello que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es precisamente lo que comentas usar la propiedad Tag, pero es muy importante que tu arreglo `arrayBanderas[]` contenga los valores enteros de las imágenes y que el método generarAleatorioBanderas() obtendrá un valor aleatorio de los contenidos en `arrayBanderas[]`.

Puedes obtener el id de los recursos de esta forma:

```
int idRecurso = getResources().getIdentifier(nombrerecurso, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

---

Al definir las imágenes en los recursos también define el ID del recurso como Tag.

```
botonUno.setImageResource(arrayBanderas[num1]);
botonUno.setTag(arrayBanderas[num1]);

botonDos.setImageResource(arrayBanderas[num2]);
botonDos.setTag(arrayBanderas[num2]);
```

para saber cuál es el recurso cargado en los botones lo realizarías de esta forma:

```
  Integer botonUnoResource = (Integer)botonUno.getTag();

  Integer botonDosResource = (Integer)botonDos.getTag();
```

Para conocer cuál es el nombre del país de acuerdo al ID del recurso, realiza un `switch` donde definas los IDs y su correspondiente país:

```
   private Static String obtenPais(int idRecurso){
     String cadenaPais = "";
     switch(idRecurso){
         case 1234:
           cadenaPais = "españa";
          break;
         case 1234:
           cadenaPais = "Argentina";
          break;
         case 1234:
           cadenaPais = "Chile";
          break;
       ...
       ...
         default:
           break;
     }  

     return cadenaPais;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

un posible enfoque, sería crear la clase ***Pais***:

```
public class Pais {
   ImageIcon bandera;
   String nombre;
   // las ubicaciones usan formato: "/imagenes/Argentina.jpg" (o similar) 
   // para poder extraer el nombre del pais.
   public Pais( String ubicacion ) {
      bandera = creoImagenConLaRuta;
      nombre = ubicacion.substring( ubicacion.lastIndexOf("/") +1, ubicacion.lastIndexOf("."));
   }

   public getBandera() {
      return bandera;
   }

   public getNombre() {
      return nombre;
   }
}
```

En la clase principal creas los paises:

```
String ubicaciones[] = { "ubicaciónA", "ubicacionB", ... };
Pais paises[] = new Pais[ cantidad ];

for( int i = 0; i < paises.length; i++ ) {
   paises[ i ] = new Pais( ubicaciones[ i ] );
}
```

luego en el método ***GenerarPregunta*** usas el obtienes el nombre y la imagen, usando el número aleatorio de la siguiente forma:

```
botonUno.setImageResource( paises[ num1 ].getBandera() );
botonDos.setImageResource( paises[ num2 ].getBandera() );
String nombrePrimerPais = paises[ num1 ].getNombre();
String nombreSegundoPais = paises[ num2 ].getNombre();
```